# JS get value of nested key with changing parent name

Tags: javascript

I need to get the value of roles in the following example.

```
const obj ={
    id: 1,
    "website.com": {
        roles: ["SuperUser"]
    }
}

const r = obj.hasOwnProperty("roles")
console.log(r)
```

Its parent objects name ("website.com") can change everytime as Im requesting it from the db. What is the best way to get this variable?

The obj would also be relatively large I just didnt include it in the example.

Comment: Why not do `obj["website.com"].roles` ?

Comment: The string "website.com" isnt always the same. It changes everytime I get the data from the api

Comment: And what happens if another object in `obj` also happens to have a roles field?

Comment: If you don't know what the parent key will be, and know only that you're looking for a nested object with the "roles" key, there's no choice but to search for it by iteration.

Comment: @chingucoding it wont thats the only place that stores the roles

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the object and exclude `id`. Example:

```
for (var x in obj) {
  if (x !== 'id') {
    console.log(obj[x].roles)
  }
}
```

EDIT (to address your question edit):

If the root object has many keys, it would probably make sense to instead either move the domain from a key to a value (for example, `domain: 'website.com'` and move the roles up (flattening the object); or you could check for a key that looks like a domain using a regex. Example: `if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$/.test(x)` rather than `if (x !== 'id')`. The regex way would probably be brittle.

EDIT 2:

You could use the hasOwnProperty check like this:

```
let roles
for (let x in obj) {
  if (obj[x].hasOwnProperty(roles)) {
    roles = obj[x])
  }
}
```

Comment: The object is actually relatively large I just didnt include all the fields in the example

Comment: It not my api I cant really change how its structured

Comment: Gotcha, I edited again. Looping through each element in `obj` and checking for a `roles` would work. It's not ideal since it means iterating through everything in the object until you find it, but since the data is formatted in that way, I don't see a better solution.

Comment: Eslint says I cannot use for in loops is there another way to do this ?

Comment: You can either add an `eslint-disable-next-line` comment above the loop, or see Mr. Polywhirl's answer, which does it without a for-in loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the roles by destructuring the `roles` property from the value of `obj['website.com']`.

If you want to do this dynamically, you will need to figure out key has a corresponding object with the property `roles`. Once you find all valid candidates, you can access the first (or whichever one you want) and then grab its value.

```js
const hasRoles = obj => Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([key, value]) =>
    value.hasOwnProperty('roles'));
  
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  "website.com": {
    roles: ["SuperUser"]
  }
}

const [ first ] = hasRoles(obj);
const [ website, { roles } ] = first;

console.log(`website = ${website} | roles = ${roles}`);
```

Alternatively, for a greedy match:

```js
const hasRolesGreedy = obj => Object.entries(obj)
  .find(([key, value]) =>
    value.hasOwnProperty('roles'));
  
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  "website.com": {
    roles: ["SuperUser"]
  }
}

const found = hasRolesGreedy(obj);
const [ website, { roles } ] = found;

console.log(`website = ${website} | roles = ${roles}`);
```

Comment: The string 'website.com' is always changing everytime I call the api

Comment: @hernandeΩ Ok, I went ahead and updated the example.

Comment: is there a way this can be simpler as I am a beginner and Im not sure what the lines defining first and the one after it do. Also If you can make hasRoles not be a function as I am getting the obj value from a variable declared in the file

Answer (score 0):

only access to the nested key like this:

```
let roles = obj["website.com"].roles;
console.log(roles);
```

That way, you will get an array, then you can iterate or get a value by the index.

Comment: The string "website.com" changes everytime I call the api

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know what the name is, you need to iterate over all properties and find the first with the roles property:

```js
const testObj ={
    id: 1,
    "website.com": {
        roles: ["SuperUser"]
    }
}

const testObj2 = {
    id: 2,
    "anotherwebsite.com":{
        roles: ["AnotherSuperUser"]
    }
}

function getRoles(obj){
    for(let x in obj){
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, x))
        {
            if(obj[x].roles){
                return obj[x].roles;
            }
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

console.log(getRoles(testObj));
console.log(getRoles(testObj2));
```

Comment: Eslint says I shouldnt use for in loops is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Updated the loop now as described by ESLint. Should be good now.